# Why std::next does not accept InputIterator?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

ISO C++11 24.3:

```
template <class InputIterator, class Distance>
void advance(InputIterator& i, Distance n);
// ...
template <class ForwardIterator>
ForwardIterator next
(
    ForwardIterator x,
    typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::difference_type n = 1
);
```

Why `std::next` does not accept `InputIterator`s?

One of legal use cases I am thinking about is:

```
first = find(next(first, x), last, 11); // ...
```

I have found appropriate [DR](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#1011):

> `next`/`prev` return an incremented iterator without changing the value of the original iterator. However, even this may invalidate an `InputIterator`. A `ForwardIterator` is required to guarantee the 'multipass' property.

But I don't understand how multipass/invalidation is related to that. Using same multipass/invalidation reasoning, we can even ban `std::find` for `InputIterator`s:

```
template<class InputIterator, class T>
InputIterator find(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& value);
```

There is nothing special about `std::next` in compare to `std::find` or `std::vector::insert(pos, first, last)` which have perfectly legal use cases for `InputIterator`s

Moreover `std::next(it, n)` can be used in generic code, which operates not only on `InputIterator`s.

Comment: Except there's `std::advance` to more accurately convey your semantics for InputIterators. We've been over this in chat

Comment: Such code can be used in generic functions which work on all iterators starting from `InputIterator`. I am interested to hear objective reasons.

Comment: On a different note.  Shouldn't all this be overhauled, in light of features from C++11.  Perhaps something like an InputIterator should be movable, not copyable, to emphasize that we can't really have to different iterators to the same source?  (But then it should all be sorted out with *ranges* and so on.  A big overhaul, perhaps.)

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Which ranges you are talking about? From D langauge, or Boost.Range-like?

Comment: @EvgenyPanasyuk To be honest, I'm not sure :-)  I did read a bit about D ranges some time ago, and I liked them a lot.  So maybe that's what I mean.  But that was a few years ago, maybe there are other solutions.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Ok. Most of D-Ranges advantages are available to iterators in form of Boost.Range (without having disadvantages of D-Ranges).

Comment: These iterators are designed to represent ranges in _flows of data_, not containers. That's why.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thats sounds totally irrelevant to Q.

Comment: @EvgenyPanasyuk: It isn't. Read the first paragraph of rici's answer to find out more about input iterators and how they work.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I do know how they work. And `std::next` has perfectly legal use cases for input iterators, as well as `std::find`.

Comment: @EvgenyPanasyuk: You're free, of course, to continue repeating that assertion on every answer and as a reply to every comment...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In effect, input iterators cannot be usefully copied, because once an input iterator is incremented, any copy left lying around is invalidated.

`std::next` takes an iterator and returns another iterator which has been advanced `n` times. You can't do that with an input iterator without invalidating the original iterator, which makes `std::next` pointless. By constrast, `std::advance` advances the specified iterator `n` times, which is fine with an input iterator.

`std::next` is the iterator generalization of `operator+(T*, size_t)`. `std::advance` is the iterator generalization of `operator+=(T*&, size_t)`. It may well be that `std::advance`, like `operator+=`, should return a reference instead of void.

It's true that there is a similar issue with `std::find` (and related functions); they, too, will invalidate any copy of the specified input iterators. But it is quite possible that the committee found that issue less serious.

Comment: `first = find(next(first, x), last, 11);` is not pointless, it is legal use-case. I don't see why you think `find` is OK, but `next` is not - there is same invalidation.

Comment: @evgeny: you're free to use `advance(first, x); first = find(first, last, 11);`. Perhaps "pointless" is not quite the right word; I mean it is pointless to pretend that it's possible to return a different iterator.

Comment: I know that it is possible to use `advance`. It is even possible to use `advance` instead of `next` for higher iterators categories. `std::next` was introduced for convenience in a first place.  "*You can't do that with an input iterator without invalidating the original iterator*" - same is applied to `std::find`.

Comment: @EvgenyPanasyuk: I think you misphrased your question. You asked "why does the standard say ...?". You meant to ask "Don't you agree that the standard is wrong?". Of course, had you phrased your question that way, it probably would have been immediately closed as "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: There can be real issue, like that use case can be really broken - maybe I missed something. But I don't see any real issue with it. That why I asked.

Comment: Wouldn't your objection be removed if `advance` returned `iterator&` instead of `void`?

Comment: No, my objection is about interface of `std::next`. Even if it uses `advance` internally, or closely related to it - interface of `std::next` should be fixed by itself. There is nothing special about `std::next` in compare to `std::find` or `std::vector::insert(pos, first, last)` which have perfectly legal use cases for `InputIterator`s.

Comment: @EvgenyPanasyuk, this is exactly about the interface of `std::next`. It promises to keep the original iterator unchanged while returning an incremented copy. It can't keep that guarantee with input iterators, so it disallows it - no matter how useful you might wish it to be. You're looking for a different function, and `std::advance` would be that function if it returned a reference to the advanced iterator.

Comment: @MarkRansom That makes sense. But strictly speaking original iterator is not changed. Invalidation is not same thing as changing. If we would count this as change, then in case of `auto x = it; ++it;` increment of `it` changes `x`, and by same reasoning also can be considered harmful.

Comment: "But strictly speaking original iterator is not changed."  Mark is saying exactly that.  `next` takes a *copy*, changes the *copy*, and therefore *invalidates* the original.  I think we all understand this, there's no point worrying over what exactly is meant by 'changed'.

Comment: The existance of a different function that disagrees eith the above reasoning demonstrates only that the above reasoning is not infinite in strength: that there are reasons to not follow it in some cases.  It does not demonstrate that there are never reasons to follow it.  Sometimes not and never are not the same thing, sometimes.  This comment has too few double and triple negatives.